# javascript: allow user to login after session times out

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, logout

I want to write a javascript program for my html webpage that forces the user after leaving the session idle for x minutes (no mouse movement or keys pressed) to reenter their password to resume the session.

Note, that I am not talking about destroying the session/closing the session as soon as the time goes out, forcing a user log out. I'm simply trying to "pause" the session by having a pop up box that the user must type username and password to resume their work.

Thanks

Comment: And what's the difference between a user logged out, and a user *not logged out but having to type username and password to resume their work*?

Comment: If you don't log the user out, couldn't the user just reload the page and continue where they left off?

Comment: Since javascript runs client side, relying on javascript to force a user to login again offers virtually no security, and is virtually pointless. Do you have a backup for if a user chooses not to run javascript at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var timeoutHolder=setTimeout(pauseSession,60000*nMinutes);
```

and then reset the time each time the user press a key

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeoutHolder);
    var timeoutHolder=setTimeout(pauseSession,60000*nMinutes);
});
```

You can also create a similar event for detecting the mouse movement. Finally, just define a pauseSession function that shows the popup.

**Some thoughts about security:** You should take into account that any measure like this executed in the client is very easy to circumvent and therefore you should only use if it does not imply a security risk.

A more sophisticated version would be to send a message to the server and keep track of the timer there, so the user can't alter it. However, the user could send fake keystrokes and key movements so it is still a vulnerable solution.

TL;DR: Everything in the client an be altered. Keys and mouse movement are detected in the client, therefore take into account that the user will always be able to disable your password prompt. Minutes since the last page load or xmlhttprequest would probably be a better measurement since it can be fully implemented in the server.